# What's the easiest way to generate a list of combinations in C++ using template meta-programming?

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, template-meta-programming

I found the SO post: [What's the easiest way to generate a list of combinations in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593787/whats-the-easiest-way-to-generate-a-list-of-combinations-in-c), which tells us how to generate at **runtime** a list of all possible combinations of a true/false tuple of size `N`.

However, I have the same question at **compile-time** if we know `N`. How would we do this with template meta-programming using template recursion? Assume that `N` is known at compile time and the only values are `true`, or `false`.

To restate the main question: "Oftentimes, you have a problem where property A can be either true or false, property B also either true or false, and so on. We want to test every combination of A being true while B being false, and so on."

```
// Say N is 3, then the following tuple of booleans would be generated
[true,true,true]
[true,true,false]
[true,false,true]
[true,false,false]
[false,true,true]
[false,true,false]
[false,false,true]
[false,false,false]
```

A possible function signature might look like:

```
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr auto boolean_combinations()
```

If possible, I would like to do this using C++17, or later.

Comment: What have you tried? In the linked post you find several alternatives. Can you translate one of them to TMP?

Comment: I wonder if recursion might be able to solve this. Base case of N = 0 and N = 1 and go from there

Comment: What you wish to do with all this combinations?

Comment: This can be easily implemented by `views::cartesian_product`.

Comment: This is pretty much `std::integer_sequence` in drag, so to speak. The only difference is that `integer_sequence` produces those `bool`s as bits in a single integer instead of as separate entities.

Comment: I wish to pass them into a function and `static_assert` their output. However, I didn't want to complicate the question.

Answer (score 4):

In C++17, you don't need template metaprogramming for that. A `constexpr` function can do the trick:

```
#include <array>

auto constexpr pow2(std::size_t exponent) -> std::size_t {
    return exponent == 0 ? 1 : 2 * pow2(exponent - 1);
}

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto boolean_combinations() {
    static_assert(N < sizeof(std::size_t));
    std::array<std::array<bool, N>, pow2(N)> list{}; // initialization needed in C++17
    for (auto i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
        for (auto j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
            list[i][j] = static_cast<bool>(i & (1 << j));
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EPjen4434)

Comment: Oh sick! Is it possible to do this using C++17 though?

Comment: @ajl123 See the edit. In C++14 it would be a bit more complicated.